# Autoencoder fails to reconstruct

Tags: keras, tensorflow, autoencoder, overfitting

I'm trying to use an autoencoder to reduce dimensionality of my features. My features are of dimension 2048. I tried to train an autoencoder to reduce the dimensionality to 50. I'm using a single hidden layer. But the loss decreases to certain extent and saturates. It's not even overfitting on the training data.

To test, I changed the dimension of dimension of hidden layer to 2048. My expectation was that now reconstruction is a trivial task and network would learn it easily. But to my surprise, the loss is even higher than in the first case. Any idea what is going wrong?

My network:

```
class MyAE:
    def __init__(self) -> None:    
        flat_inputs = Input(shape=(2048,), name='flat_inputs')
        bottleneck = Dense(units=2048)(flat_inputs)
        flat_outputs = Dense(units=2048)(bottleneck)

        self.model = Model(inputs=flat_inputs, outputs=flat_outputs)
        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
        self.model.summary(print_fn=print)
```

I'm training my network as

```
num_samples = inputs.shape[0]
self.model.fit(x=inputs, y=inputs, batch_size=num_samples, epochs=self.num_epochs, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Probably choking.  Information works like fluid flow, or vise versa.  You need a set of slow steps to get through the encoder to the decoder, and you need a few steps to get from the bottleneck back to the reconstruction.  Doing it in one step for a sufficiently complex form, without even a grid search on bottleneck size, is often likely to be problematic.

Comment: what are your activation functions?

Comment: Linear. Doesn't change much with relu or sigmoid either